# Combine dictionary

Tags: python, list, random, dictionary

I'm a python beginner. What do I do if i want to combine two dictionaries like these:

```
dwarf items={'coins':30,'power':11,'Knives':20,'beer':10,'pistol':2}
caves=[('A','B','C','D','E','F','G')]
```

I wanna "the dwarf" randomly drops items in any of these caves

I tried the zip function but didn't work the way i expected. 
the output should look like this:

```
cache={'A':0,'B':['coins':30],'C':['Knives':20},'D':0,'E':0,'F':0,'G':0}
```

Comment: Caves isn't a dictionary. You have a lot of syntax errors in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are maybe looking for something like the following:

```
dwarf_items = {'coins': 30, 'power': 11, 'Knives': 20, 'beer': 10, 'pistol': 2}
caves = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
drop_chance = 0.4  # change this to make it more or less likely an item will drop
cache = {}
for cave in caves:
    if dwarf_items and random.random() < drop_chance:
        item = random.choice(dwarf_items.keys())
        cache[cave] = {item: dwarf_items.pop(item)}
    else:
        cache[cave] = {}
```

Here are a few examples of output that I got with this over a few runs:

```
>>> cache
{'A': {}, 'C': {}, 'B': {'Knives': 20}, 'E': {'beer': 10}, 'D': {'power': 11}, 'G': {'coins': 30}, 'F': {}}
```

---

```
>>> cache
{'A': {}, 'C': {'power': 11}, 'B': {'pistol': 2}, 'E': {'Knives': 20}, 'D': {'beer': 10}, 'G': {}, 'F': {'coins': 30}}
```

---

```
>>> cache
{'A': {}, 'C': {}, 'B': {}, 'E': {'beer': 10}, 'D': {}, 'G': {}, 'F': {}}
```

Comment: May it would be better to just to get a shuffled copy of caves and put items respectively into that list?

Comment: These code did work for me, what version are you using?

Comment: You may need to add `import random` to the top of the code.  This was Python 2.7 but this should work in other versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I think is probably close to what you're looking for:

```
import random

cave_names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']
item_names = ['coins', 'power', 'knives', 'beer', 'pistol']

# Create the dictionary of caves, all of which have no items to start
caves = {cave : {item : 0 for item in item_names} for cave in cave_names}

# Randomly distribute the dwarf's items into the caves
dwarf_items = {'coins' : 30, 'power' : 11, 'knives' : 20, 'beer' : 10, 'pistol' : 2}
for key, value in dwarf_items.iteritems():
    for i in range(value):
        # Give away all of the items
        cave = random.choice(cave_names)
        caves[cave][key] += 1
        # Take the item away from the dwarf
        dwarf_items[key] -= 1

print(caves)
```

Here's an example of what caves looks at the end, after all of the dwarf's items have been distributed into caves randomly:

```
{'A': {'beer': 2, 'coins': 4, 'knives': 1, 'pistol': 1, 'power': 1},
 'B': {'beer': 0, 'coins': 3, 'knives': 7, 'pistol': 0, 'power': 0},
 'C': {'beer': 1, 'coins': 2, 'knives': 1, 'pistol': 0, 'power': 3},
 'D': {'beer': 3, 'coins': 8, 'knives': 3, 'pistol': 0, 'power': 2},
 'E': {'beer': 2, 'coins': 4, 'knives': 2, 'pistol': 1, 'power': 5},
 'F': {'beer': 2, 'coins': 7, 'knives': 5, 'pistol': 0, 'power': 0},
 'G': {'beer': 0, 'coins': 2, 'knives': 1, 'pistol': 0, 'power': 0}}
```

Comment: This one didn't work, the error message is the 'dict' has no attribute to 'iteritems'

Comment: @user3285116 You must be on Python 3 then. iteritems() was renamed to simply items()